"Library 'Pods-Project Name' not found" (ios + cordova + xcode)
I'm trying to compile an app for the ios platform via cordova and xcode, which I've never done before.
The steps, as outlined to me, are:

sudo cordova build ios
open project in Xcode
build app
archive app
submit to app store from archive

I'm having an issue with building the app inside Xcode - getting an error message "Library 'Pods-Project Name' not found", (and then one "Linked command failed with exit code 1" but that's likely a knock-on effect from the first error).
How do I fix this? I've never even gone near a MacBook before being told we needed to getting this ios app compiled, so I'm completely at a loss!

You need to open the workspace in xcode and not the project.

thanks - on inspection I found I had opened  ($cordovaRoot)/platforms/ios/projectname.xcodeproj and not ($cordovaRoot)/platforms/ios/projectname.xcworkspace
Everything seems to be working as expected now, thank you!
